# Plesk wordpress multisite, using sub domains

Tags: wordpress, subdomain, plesk, multisite

I have setup wordpress multisite, I have also added a second site via dashboard. However when accessing that second website I am getting this error - The requested URL /wp-admin/ was not found on this server.

I have also added the sub domain on the Plesk control panel, but im still getting the same error..

Any suggestions? I realise this may of been asked already, so i do apologise! but everything seems to be with cpanel and not Plesk.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use aliases like sub.domain.tld instead of subdomains.